# How Object class reference can receive the primitive type array base address?

Tags: java, arrays, object

```
class Demo{
    static void receive(Object temp){
    System.out.println(temp);
    }
}


class Test{
    public static void main(String ... a){
    int arr[] = new int[5];
    Demo.receive(arr);
    }
}
```

see output..

The question arises how method 'receive(Object temp)' in Demo class can receive the base address of 
primitive integer type array.

If Object class reference variable can receive the primitive type array base address then one thing
is clear that the base address must be of either Object class type or a sub class of Object class type..

so Do there exists some class for primitive type array address too?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, `arrays` are also `objects`, `int` is a primitive, not an int array. So, you can pass an array where an object is expected.

Next, in `MyClass@5db9742` the number after the `@` represents the Object's *hashcode*.

Comment: @nihal - `[]` is an indexing operator, it is not a *class*. Arrays are objects in which each element is of a particular type. You actually have `Arrays` class to work on arrays.

Comment: but int arr[] = new int[5] doesn't mean that arr[] refers to Arrays class object...
If it was true then output should be: java.util.Arrays@hexcode

Comment: @nihal - "[I" is the Java runtime library's way of saying "the type of an array of ints".  The type doesn't have a name / identifier that you can use in Java.

Comment: @Stephen C - Exactly ,I want to Know the class "the class of an array of ints" ..

Comment: @nihal - It is what it is.  It is an anonymous type that inherits methods from `java.lang.Object`.  Strictly speaking, it is not a `class`, but at runtime it is represented by a `java.lang.Class` object, just like a normal class, and you can get hold of it by calling `getClass()` on an array object.  Read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.8

Comment: @nihal - That is the syntax of Java. Like *stephen* says, internally, the Java Runtime and the compiler *understand* that you want to specify a group of integers when you do `int[]`. Internally all reference types are `Type extends <Object>`. So, they all get the properties of Object.

Comment: In my case, object of `Object` class accepted `boolean` (primitive data type variable, I was surprised, how is this possible ?

Comment: @AkashSavairam - `boolean` gets *autoboxed* to a `Boolean` which is an `Object`

Answer (score 2):

> The question arises how method 'receive(Object temp)' in Demo class can receive the base address of primitive integer type array.

Java does not allow pure Java applications to see or manipulate addresses.

So the answer is that it can't.

---

If you really, really need to get the address of an object (including an array), then it is possible to step outside of pure Java into the JVM implementation; e.g. using JNI or JNA to call native code, or using the `Unsafe` class.  But if you do that, you need to be very careful.  One mistake and you can hard crash the JVM!!

And besides, you shouldn't need to do this in a normal program.

---

> If Object class reference variable can receive the primitive type array base address then one thing is clear that the base address must be of either Object class type or a sub class of Object class type.

If you are trying to say that (for example) `int[]` is a subtype of `Object`, then that is correct.  But you don't need to resort to contorted logic involving "base addresses" to deduce that.  It is actually specified in the Java Language Specification.

For example:

> [4.3.2. The Class Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.2)
>
> The class Object is a superclass (§8.1.4) of all other classes.
>
> All class and array types inherit (§8.4.8) the methods of class Object ...

And there is lots more in the JLS about the relationship between objects, classes, types and arrays.

Answer (score 0):

As u might know Object class is superclass of all objects in Java. Moreover the function of new operator is same as creating object and return reference of that object. Hence arrays creation are similar to object creation. And if you are looking to find class for primitive array types you should go for wrapper classes http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberclasses.html. Might it help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

These methods might help you if you are interested in inspecting the object:

```
    temp.getClass().isPrimitive();
    temp.getClass().isArray();
    temp.getClass().isInterface();
    temp.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Object.class);
```